# changing values from specific columns

Tags: sed, awk, grep

The following sed command is working as expected. What I need to do is to change the null (\n) to 0 only in the second column.

```
# cat nulltest.txt 
1   abc
1   \N
\N  xyz

# sed 's/\\N/0/' nulltest.txt 
1   abc
1   0
0   xyz
```

Expected results :

```
1   abc
1   0
\N  xyz
```

Data is separated by tab "\t"

Comment: This is just an example. Actual file is more than 10GB and has 16 columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
kent$  echo "1   abc
1   \N
\N  xyz"|awk '{gsub(/\\N/,"0",$2)}1'|column -t
1   abc
1   0
\N  xyz
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use below regex in your `sed` expression which ensures that `\N` is in 2nd column.

```
^([^\t]+\t)\\N(\t)
```

So your `sed` expression will look something like below

```
sed -r -i 's/^([^\t]+\t)\\N(\t)/\10\2/g' nulltest.txt
```

**Explanation:**

`^([^\t]+\t)`: will match `1` followed by `\t` and `()` around the regex makes it first group.

`\\N` : will match `\N`

`(\t)`: It the `tab` after second column which is second group.

In the substitue section of `sed` notice use of `\1` and `\2` which represents the ***first and second group*** from the regex which in your case is `1 followed by \t` and `\t` respectively. So it will keep group one and two and replace rest of the matched string with `0`.

In my testing I used below input file

```
abcdefgh
3   abc \N  \N  \N
123 \N  \N  \N
\N  \Nxyz
```

and the output I get is

```
abcdefgh
3   abc \N  \N  \N
123adsa 0   \N  \N
\N  \Nxyz
```

Notice that exactly `\N` from `2nd` column is replaced. Even if there are any number of columns with `\N` this sed expression will replace `\N` only from `2nd` column.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
sed -r 's/^([^\t]+\t)\\N/\10/' nulltest.txt
```

Comment: if your file is 10GB size and you have a lot of fields in a row, for sure awk is easier to use than sed. but a csv parser should be better... with \t set as separator.